# I Am unable to install gem

Tags: rubygems

I am unable to install gem i tried many online resources still not working, am getting this error when am installing

$ gem install susy --http-proxy ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'susy' (>= 0), here is why:           Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Failed to open TCP connection to http_proxy:80 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "http_proxy" port 80) (http://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your gemfile should have the following line:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

(notice it's https and not http)

Comment: Thanks for the help , after using https:// it is throwing same error

$ gem install susy
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'susy' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Failed to open TCP connection to http_proxy:80 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "http_proxy" port 80) (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Have you tried adding `gem 'susy'` to your gemfile and running bundle update/bundle install? Or possibly in the cmd line `gem install susy --source http://rubygems.org`

Comment: Rixcy

am trying to install from git bash and i tried your code , it is happening same please check

Comment: $ gem install susy --source http://rubygems.org
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'susy' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Failed to open TCP connection to http_proxy:80 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "http_proxy" port 80) (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
          Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT:

Comment: Failed to open TCP connection to http_proxy:80 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "http_proxy" port 80) (http://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)